# Cassandra instability that causes Timeouts on queries

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra 3.11.1, 5-node cluster

1. All works well till yesterday
2. But yesterday (without visible cause) we start to get random Read/Write Timeout Exception. Any query can be executed for 1ms and after it, repeat and Timeout, repeat and again 1ms - so application cannot work.

I'm not an admin (developer) but i start to looking for something in nodetool and have a look at `tpstats` and it's Dropped part, and what i see.

```
Message type           Dropped
READ                       396
RANGE_SLICE                485
_TRACE                  496047
HINT                         0
MUTATION                  1139
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
BATCH_STORE                 28
BATCH_REMOVE                 0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  0
```

For me - it's sign that something is very and very wrong but i cannot understand how to diagnose it more detailed, what is cause and how to fix.

After some experiments we see that timeout caused if token owned by certain node,
for example `select id from mytable where it = '<token from invalid node>'` - it will be fail with timeout every 5 runs.

Is where any suggestions???

Comment: what is in the logs on that node?

Comment: Have you tried disabling trace probability? If its dropping _TRACE you are massively overwhelming it since thats just a CL.ANY request

Comment: not yet, will try to disable it. But before this moment it wasn't problem

Comment: ./nodetool gettraceprobability - current level is 0

Answer (score 0):

Some diagnostics.

In logs 2 of nodes was spam each other (from system.log) with

```
2018-05-23 10:05:38,281 INFO  [HintsDispatcher:33] 
HintsDispatchExecutor.java:289 deliver Finished hinted handoff of file 
c53d4133-c681-4903-8399-60dfd8fa786f-1526980061074-1.hints to endpoint 
/111.11.11.111: c53d4133-c681-4903-8399-60dfd8fa786f, partially
```

many and many.

After restart one of this nodes, hints was deleted and situation was normalized.

But still no info - why is it so and how to prevent...